# How to send custom headers in spring boot GET Request?

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman, backend, request-headers

I have an api which looks like this:

```java
@Get
@Path("/{user_id}")
public Response getUser(@RequestHeader(name="email", required = false) String email, @PathParam("user_id") String userId, @QueryParam("pref") Boolean pref)
```

When I am sending a sample request through postman, I am not able to fetch the value of email even though i am providing it in the headers. It keeps showing `email: ""`

What am I missing?

I have tried changing some configs but its of no use. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: You're using both header and request param in same request. Fetching value method of these two are different. Are you somehow mixing up them? If you share how you fetch, we can help more

Comment: did you try to use `@RequestHeader(value="email"...)` instead of `@RequestHeader(name="email"...)` ?

Comment: @cyberbrain, yes I tried doing both. It's not working

Comment: @GökhanPolat, I don't want to expose the email in the query param or the request param, hence using the headers

Comment: Did you try another names? It is possible you have some old proxy or filter in between, which doesn't like a custom header with the name "email".

Comment: `@GetMapping("/test") String test(@RequestHeader(value = "email", required = false) String email) { return email; }` just works well